# Creating table layout in WYSIWYG editor

Tags: editor, wysiwyg, post-editor

I am having a design as mentioned in the image.

[image]

The content for these should go in a widget. How I am achieving this right now is: by editing it in the WYSIWYG editor by using spaces between the texts. Is there any other way to align this properly.

I have come across such layouts for many of my projects and till now I have been using spaces to align them. But in my recent project I saw that using spaces is not correct solution because in my case, the font I am using behaves bit different on different browsers and thus the space is not consistent.

So, using spaces I am getting correct result on chrome but on firefox the spacing is not the same.

Result on firefox:

[image]

I guess there might be a better solution for creating such tabled layout in WYSIWYG editor. Please let me know if there is any. Thanks for your time.

Comment: You should use a mono-spaced font - https://youtu.be/SsoOG6ZeyUI

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. and the video. LOL. but I should use the same font. So, is there no way I can achieve the same without using spaces at all.

Comment: http://tympanus.net/codrops/css_reference/text-align/ - wed dev 101. You can make 3 cols in a table. [ align-right, center, align-left ]. But this isn't the place for CSS discussion. http://stackoverflow.com/a/9824175/5623301

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you are not using table? Spaces are ridiculus. On WYSIWYG editor select table with 2 columns and 3 rows, align items in left column to left, and in right to center and everything should work fine.

EDIT. Ok, I see where is the problem. TinyMCE (WYSIWYG editor) has table option, but by default it is disabled in WordPress. You can download plugin, for example [TinyMCE Advanced](https://wordpress.org/plugins/tinymce-advanced/), and enable various and powerful TinyMCE options. Also, you can switch view to text editor and add table in HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Cell</td><td>Cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Cell</td><td>Cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Cell</td><td>Cell</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```